# How to read php object relations(custom attributes) in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, activerecord, yii2

I have created relation in Task model for activities

```
public funtion getActivitiesSum()
{
     return $this->hasMany(Activities::className(),['task_id'=>'id'])->sum('amount');

}
```

I'm getting the right sum, and calculation is ok. Query is also ok and when test to print sum in foreach loop it's printing right sum amount.

```
$tasks =  Task::find()->where(['project_id'=>$id])->all();
```

In view file I'm using javascript function on tasks variable. I have tried to pass with Json::encode, but can't read relation custom attribute **activitiesSum** . Return undifined when I tried to print.

```
return $this->render('view',[
    'tasks' => Json::encode($tasks)
]);
```

Also I have tried to return without encode, but can't read varibale in javascript. ***Array to string conversion error***

How can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't. You have to loop through the `$tasks` array and call `getActivitiesSum()` in each element. The `find()` cannot include your function, since it is not a relation, and you cannot call PHP's object methods from js.

I would create a separate array, indexed by Task's `id`, with the activity amount of each task:

```
$tasks =  Task::find()->where(['project_id'=>$id])->all();
$activities_count = [];
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
  $activites_count[$task->id] = $task->getActivitiesSum();
}
```

Now you render the view with `$tasks` and `$activities_count`.

Comment: I already get the right sum, as I said in foreach loop $task->activitiesSum returning the right amout. Problem is that object don't display it when encode in json.

Comment: I know. What I'm telling you is that, as far as I know, you have to create a separate array to store the activity count for each task, and work with two arrays (the activities amount array can be indexed by Tasks id, so that is easy to work with)

Comment: Thank you, it can be solution, for now. But I would like if someone can describe problem with json and relative model sum.